# Посчитать число слов в файле

Tags: c++

Есть файл. В нём несколько строк. Необходимо посчитать число слов в нем.

```
int countWords() {
int words = 0;
ifstream in("in.txt");
char ch;
while (in.get(ch)) {
    if (ch == ' '||ch=='/n')
        words++;
}
return words;
}
```

Данный код считает слова в первой строке. Как исправить?

Comment: А если два пробела подряд будут стоять, то это будет считаться за слово? Нужно тогда проверять, чтобы предыдущий символ был минимум буквой.

Comment: Так посчитать количество пробелов, или количество слов? Начните с постановки правильного ТЗ (без которого результат один - ХЗ). Да и не воспроизводится ваша ошибка - считает все пробелы до конца файла...

Answer (score 3):

Там разве не '\n' должно быть , а не '/n' ?

Comment: Всё равно не пашет